# Оптимизация обновления RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Все мы знаем хрестоматийный пример работы с `RecyclerView`:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// items - список объектов для отображения.
DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(this, items);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Из этого примера вытекает простой способ обновления `RecyclerView` - передать в адаптер новый список `items`. Однако это не всегда приемлемо, потому, что приводит к полной перерисовке `RecyclerView`, что вызывает тормоза в GUI при большом количестве объектов.

Есть ли возможность обновлять `RecyclerView` не передавая новый `items` целиком, а добавляя новые объекты к уже имеющимся, чтобы `RecyclerView` отрисовывал только недостающую часть?

Comment: можно [использовать DiffUtil](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html) для обновления только тех элементов, которые изменились

Comment: @pavloff, спасибо! Помогло! Оформите пожалуйста как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Есть класс DiffUtil. Он сравнит два набора данных: старый и новый, выяснит, какие произошли изменения, и с помощью notify методов оптимально обновит адаптер.

От нас требуется только наследовать класс DiffUtil.Callback и реализовать несколько его абстрактных методов.

```
public class ListDiffUtils extends DiffUtil.Callback {

    private final List<Data> oldData;

    private final List<Data> newData;

    StepsListDiffUtils(@NonNull List<Data> oldData, @NonNull List<Data> newData) {

        this.oldData = oldData;

        this.newData = newData;

    }

    @Override

    public int getOldListSize() {

        return oldData.size();

    }

    @Override

    public int getNewListSize() {

        return newData.size();

    }

    @Override

    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {

        return oldData.get(oldItemPosition).getDate() == newData.get(newItemPosition).getDate();

}

    @Override

    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {

        return oldData.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newData.get(newItemPosition));

    }
}
```

Используем наш созданный DiffUtilCallback

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.StepsViewHolder> {

    private List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    //some code

    public void updateAdapter(List<Data> data) {

        DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new ListDiffUtils(dataList, data));

        dataList.clear();

        dataList.addAll(data);

        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);

    }

}
```

https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html здесь можно рассмотреть подробный пример.